# Equal space between buttons in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-linearlayout

I have four buttons arranged vertically in a LinearLayout.

[image: buttons]

I want the space between the buttons and the space between the topmost button and the top of the linear layout and the space between the bottom most button and the bottom of the layout, to be the same.

In the attached figure, the spaces are depicted as red paths.
I want all the spaces to be of the same size.

How would I go about achiving my goal?

```
<LinearLayout
            p1:orientation="vertical"
            p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:id="@+id/mainButtonLayout">
            <Button
                p1:text="xxx"
                p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                p1:id="@+id/saButton"
                p1:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                p1:background="@drawable/roundedBlue"
                p1:minHeight="33dp"
                p1:minWidth="175dp"
                p1:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
            <Button
                p1:text="xxxx"
                p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                p1:id="@+id/rButton"
                p1:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                p1:background="@drawable/roundedBlue"
                p1:minHeight="33dp"
                p1:minWidth="175dp"
                p1:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
            <Button
                p1:text="xxxxx"
                p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                p1:id="@+id/sButton"
                p1:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                p1:background="@drawable/roundedBlue"
                p1:minHeight="33dp"
                p1:minWidth="175dp"
                p1:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
            <Button
                p1:text="xxxxx"
                p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                p1:id="@+id/pButton"
                p1:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                p1:background="@drawable/roundedBlue"
                p1:minHeight="33dp"
                p1:minWidth="175dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use weightsum in your LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
...
android:weightSum="4.0">`
```

In every Button put
layout_height = 0dp , layout_weight = 1, top and bottom margin according to your need but same in every button.

```
<Button....
...
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1.0"
android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
/>
```

for more info : [read this document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3AweightSum)

Answer (score 1):

To place the buttons in the center of the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    ... >
```

To put spaces between the buttons, i can think of two options. The first is to use `android:layout_marginTop` on all the buttons except the first. The second is to make an empty shape drawable in XML with a hardcoded size and use it as a divider for the LinearLayout

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <size android:width="your_dimension_here"
        android:height="your_dimension_here" />

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape

<LinearLayout
    android:divider="@drawable/divider_space"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    ... >
```

Comment: Would your solution be resolution independent?

Comment: @Pétur It is if you use a dimension specified in dp units, regardless which method you prefer for the spacing between the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in between your views,

```
<View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

hopefully i will try to complete your requriement.  try this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
         />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
       />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTwitter"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add p1:gravity="center" to your linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout
p1:layout_width="match_parent"
p1:layout_height="match_parent"
p1:orientation="vertical"
p1:gravity="center"
p1:id="@+id/mainButtonLayout">
```

Comment: That did not work, it stretches the buttons to the left and to the right but the vertical space remains the same.